# What happens if we don't return 0 from std::qsort?

Tags: c++, std, qsort

According to the documentation qsort is supposed to be used like:

```
std::qsort(a, size, sizeof *a, [](const void* a, const void* b)
    {

        if(*a < *b) return -1;
        if(*a> *a) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
```

If the values are the same and I don't mind which comes first, or I prefer one to come before the other based on some other variable, can I do?

```
if(*a < *b) return -1;
else return 1;
```

Comment: No you can't because then qsort is going to be unable to decide which of two equal elements should go first. You have a situation where cmp(a,b) and cmp(b,a) both return 1 (for equal elements a and b) This is likely to mess with the qsort algorithm.

Comment: consider using `std::sort` rather than `qsort`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the C11 standard (7.22.5/4),

> When the same objects (consisting of `size` bytes, irrespective of their current positions
>   in the array) are passed more than once to the comparison function, the results shall be
>   consistent with one another. That is, for `qsort` they shall define a total ordering on the
>   array, and for `bsearch` the same object shall always compare the same way with the
>   key.

Your comparison function violates this requirement, because it returns 1 whenever the two values are equal. When `qsort` compares two equal values `x` and `y` using your comparison function, it will return 1, telling `qsort` that `x > y`. If later it compares `y` and `x`, then the comparison function will again return 1, meaning that `y > x`. These two results are not consistent with each other.

This requirement is incorporated by reference into C++17 ([alg.c.library]/2). Because the requirement is violated, the behaviour is undefined.